# How to fill in the PTO/SB64 form

Tags: sb64

How to fill in the Patent PTO/SB64 form
I did not receive the allowance and publication notice.
Do I need to pay the following fees?
(2) Reply and/or issue fee;
(3) Terminal disclaimer with disclaimer fee – required for all utility and plant applications filed before June 8, 1995, and for all design applications; and.

Comment: You are saying there was a Notice of Allowance but you didn't see it and the application went abandoned?

Comment: And I assume it was *not* filed before June 8 1995?